# OrientDb: Error while importing Neo4J database through GraphML importation

Tags: neo4j, orientdb

I'm trying to import a Neo4j database, I'm following these steps:

- Export the Neo4j database to a graphml file as explained in this page: [Import from Neo4j using GraphML](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/admin/Import-from-Neo4j-using-GraphML.html)
- Import the graphml file to a new database in OrientDb.

I receive the following error:

```
!ERROR: Error on importing GraphML
-> Current state = END_ELEMENT is not among the states CHARACTERS , COMMENT , CDATA , SPACE valid for getTextStart()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are following an deprecated process to import from Neo4j to OrientDB. From the docs linked by you:

> This is a **legacy strategy** to migrate from Neo4j. The new strategy is
>   to migrate using the Neo4j to OrientDB Importer.

You should use the new "Neo4j to OrientDB Importer" strategy, presented in [this link](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/neo4j-to-orientdb-importer/).

Comment: I also used the Neo4j importer from the Dashboard and it got stuck. I'm using the OrientDb ver. 2.2, I see that your link is to the 3.3 version, I'll try to follow that tutorial. 
Thank you.

Comment: Now It seems to work but the importation fail:
with a "Killed" message.

Comment: @OaicStef so the import process is not working yet, right?

Comment: It failed but I suppose that it is due to some wrong configuration on the Server. It seems that the process is killed and it is not leaving any logging. It is really strange. Furthermore the importation from graphml is not deprecated, at least in the Official page.

Comment: @OaicStef There is no error message? Only a "Killed"?

Comment: Yep, only a Killed.

Comment: @OaicStef Maybe you should ask a new question about it... This way the whole community can help you.